Why do my duplicate records only contain one record item?
Data is being pulled into my Duplicate Record Set that only has one duplicate record item? What could potentially be the cause of this? I'm new to Sales Force - is it that someone could of deleted/merged the items within the record but the record still remains within the duplicate record set?

As per this help article,

when records are no longer deemed to be "potential duplicates", the Duplicate Record Sets still remain

The duplicate sets aren't automatically deleted even if there are no more duplicates and need to be deleted manually, as you suspected in your question.
